# Convergence of one series

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n, \cdots$ are positive real numbers such that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)=+\infty$, we can affirm that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_k}{(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k)^2}$ converges?

I try use some comparison test, but I have not success. Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: This was asked before, but at the moment I can't find a duplicate question. The argument is: Let $S_k = \lambda_1 + \dotsc + \lambda_k$. If $S_k \to +\infty$, note that $$\frac{\lambda_k}{S_k^2} \leqslant \frac{\lambda_k}{S_kS_{k-1}} = \frac{S_k - S_{k-1}}{S_kS_{k-1}} = \frac{1}{S_{k-1}} - \frac{1}{S_k},$$ and you get the convergence by telescoping.

Comment: @DanielFischer The dup you are seeking is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1296203/215011 . But note the OP's hypothesis is $\sum S_k=\infty$, not $S_k\to\infty$

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. Very good your solution.

Comment: @grand_chat Thanks. I guess that the assumption of divergence got mangled on the way, since unless all $\lambda_k$ are zero, the partial sums don't converge to $0$ and the series of partial sums diverges trivially. And if $\sum \lambda_k < +\infty$, then we have convergence by comparison too, so actually no condition except positivity is needed.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, I suspect the intended hypothesis is $S_k\to\infty$. I've collected your comments into a slightly simpler answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is true.** Let $S_k\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j$.
By assumption, $\lim_{k\to\infty} S_k = \infty$.
Now,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda_k}{S_k^2} 
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{S_k-S_{k-1}}{S_k^2}
$$
which "should" remind you of something (the discrete analogue) of $\int\frac{f'}{f^2}$. This is no coincidence, and one can make this formal via [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda_k}{S_k^2} 
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{S_k^2}\cdot (S_k-S_{k-1}).
$$
We know that

- $\sum_k (S_k-S_{k-1})$ is a convergent series (it is a telescopic series, and $\lim_{k\to\infty} S_k = \infty$).
- The sequence $(\frac{1}{S_k^2})_k$ is monotone decreasing (as $(S_k)_k$ is monotone increasing: indeed, the $\lambda_k$'s are positive)
- The sequence $(\frac{1}{S_k^2})_k$ is bounded (as it converges; or, equivalently, is monotone decreasing and positive).

Then the series
$
\sum_{k} \frac{1}{S_k^2}\cdot (S_k-S_{k-1})
$
is convergent by Abel's test.

Answer (score 1):

If the $\lambda$'s are all positive, no other hypothesis is needed. Write $S_k:=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_k$. For $k\ge2$ we have
$$0<\frac{\lambda_k}{S_k^2}\le\frac{S_k-S_{k-1}}{S_{k-1}S_k}=\frac1{S_{k-1}}-\frac1{S_k}.$$
By telescoping, the sum of the first $n$ terms satisfies
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\lambda_k}{S_k^2}\le\frac{\lambda_1}{S_1^2}+ \left(\frac1{S_1}-\frac1{S_n}\right)\le\frac2{\lambda_1}.$$ So the partial sums are increasing and bounded above, hence the series in question converges.