# If sequence $a_n>0$ is decreasing to $0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$, prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{e^{S_n}}<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If sequence $a_n>0$ is decreasing to $0$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$, is it always true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{e^{S_n}}<\infty$, where $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ is the partial sum? If yes, how to prove; if no, is there any counterexample?

---

I have tried $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, in that case $e^{S_n}\sim n$ when $n$ is large, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{e^{S_n}} \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$. I also tried $a_n=\frac{1}{n\ln n}$, in this case $e^{S_n}\sim \ln n$ when $n$ is large, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{e^{S_n}} \sim \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\ln n)^2}<\infty$ by Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: What have you tried?  For example, can you think of any simpler series to compare against?

Comment: I have tried $a_n=1/n^p$ (where $p\leq 1$) and $a_n=1/(n\log n)$, computation shows that in both cases, the desired series converge.

Comment: @William: You may want to add this to the question: as of now it has no context. And perhaps explain why the desired series converges in these cases. As a result of these additions you could be able to find a solution yourself.

Comment: the easiest way is to use that $e^{-S_n} \le \frac{\int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_n}e^{-x}dx}{a_n}, n \ge 1$ where $S_0=0$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only condition needed is that $a_n>0$ and then $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_ne^{-S_n} \le 1$ since with $S_0=0<S_1<S_2<...$ one has $$e^{-S_n} \le \frac{\int_{S_{n-1}}^{S_n}e^{-x}dx}{a_n}, n \ge 1$$

Then $\sum_{n=1}^N a_ne^{-S_n} \le \int_0^{S_N}e^{-x}dx \le 1$

Comment: Very neat answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Since $1+x\leq e^x$, we have $ a_n\leq e^{a_n}-1$. Multiply both sides by $e^{-S_n}$ to get
$$\frac {a_n}{e^{S_n}}\leq e^{-S_n+a_n}-e^{-S_n}\tag{1}$$
Because $a_n\leq a_{n-1}$, we have $e^{-S_n+a_n}\leq e^{-S_n+a_{n-1}}=e^{-S_{n-1}}$. Applying this to $(1)$ gives
$$\frac {a_n}{e^{S_n}}\leq e^{-S_{n-1}}-e^{-S_n}$$
The right-hand side is telescopic:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {a_n}{e^{S_n}}\leq 1-e^{-S_n}\longrightarrow 1$$