# If $a_n > 1$ is a sequence of integers and $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ the partial sums, is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{s_n s_{n-1}^{1/2 }}<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

A frequently asked (and answered) question is,
whether the following (or something very similar) is true:

Given a sequence of positive real numbers $a_n > 0$ and the corresponding sequence of partial sums
$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, the series
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{s_n s_n^{\varepsilon}}$ is convergent.

Examples are:

- [If sequence $a_n>0$ is decreasing to $0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$, prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{e^{S_n}}<\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372811/if-sequence-a-n0-is-decreasing-to-0-and-sum-k-1-infty-a-n-infty-pro)
- [Suppose $a_n>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ diverges. Determine convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_n}{s_n^2}}$, where $s_n=\sum^n a_n$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296203/suppose-a-n0-and-sum-n-1-inftya-n-diverges-determine-convergence-o?rq=1)
- [Convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{S_n ^{1 + \epsilon}}$ where $S_n = \sum_{i = 1} ^ n a_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55670/convergence-of-sum-fraca-ns-n-1-epsilon-where-s-n-sum-i-1?rq=1)
- [Rudin: Problem Chp3.11 and need advice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411817/rudin-problem-chp3-11-and-need-advice?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I need the statement slightly modified:

Given a series of integers $a_n > 1$ without any further assumptions (no convergence or monotony), is it true that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{s_n \cdot s_{n-1}^{1/2}}$ is convergent?

Answer (score 2):

We have:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{s_n \sqrt{s_{n-1}}} &= \frac{s_n-s_{n-1}}{\sqrt{s_n}\cdot\sqrt{s_n s_{n-1}}}\\ &\le \frac{s_n-s_{n-1}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\sqrt{s_n}+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}\right)\cdot\sqrt{s_n s_{n-1}}} \\&= 2\cdot \frac{\sqrt{s_n}-\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}{\sqrt{s_n s_{n-1}}})\\
&=2\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{s_{n-1}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{s_{n}}} \right) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

As $a_n >1$, we must have $s_n \xrightarrow{n\to+\infty}+\infty$, from $(1)$, we can deduce
$$\color{red}{\sum_{i=2}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n}{s_n \sqrt{s_{n-1}}} \le }2\sum_{i=2}^{+\infty}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{s_{n-1}}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{s_{n}}} \right)=2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s_{1}}} - \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{s_{n}}} \right) =\color{red}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{s_1}}}$$

The sum is then convergent.

Comment: @geetha290krm No, it's correct. Just remind that $2\sqrt{s_n} \ge \sqrt{s_n}  + \sqrt{s_{n-1}} $ as $\{s_n\}_n$ is increasing series.

Comment: Sorry! Your proof is fine and I have upvoted it.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very helpful.

Comment: @Ivo You're welcome!